# Server method not returning data to client

Tags: meteor

Here's the method located in `server\twitter\methods.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Meteor.methods({
        searchTweets:function(term){
            T.get('search/tweets', { q: term, count: 2 }, function(err, data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the event code located in `client\search.js`

```
Template.DashboardSearch.events({
    "click #btnSearchTweets": function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var term = $('#searchTerm').val();

        Meteor.call('searchTweets', term, function(err, result) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(result);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (result) {
                Session.set('tweetData', result);
            }
        });
        $('#searchTerm').val("");
    }
});
```

The thing is, the 2 `console.log()` statements in the search.js file both return `undefined` while the `console.log()` in methods.js returns the expected twitter api data, any clues?

Comment: Put the method in the shared folder. And call it in a Template.rendered function.

Comment: Also move it away from Meteor.startup, Meteor.methods are meant to be stand-alone

Comment: @S.19LaBG Thanks for the feedback but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @Sindis Was trying to debug the thing & tried to put it in the startup function. I posted my answer down below if you're interested.

Comment: You will need to either use a "sync" (wrapped async) HTTP call or return a promise. See [this gist](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399) for the promise option.

Answer (score 1):

I might've mislead some people with how I framed my question.

The thing is; I was using the meteorhacks:npm package & the `T` represent a `Meteor.npmRequire()` package.

This is how my method looks like now:

```
Meteor.methods({
    searchTweets:function(term){
        var tweets = Async.runSync(function(done) {
            T.get('search/tweets', { q: term, count: 2 }, function(err, data) {
                done(null, data);
            });
        });
        return tweets.result;
    }
});
```

Everything seems to be working correctly now.